# Prove that if there exists an integer a such that $a^2 \equiv −1 \text{ (mod p) then } p ≡ 1 \text{ (mod 4)}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let p be a prime number which is not equal to 2. Prove that if there exists an integer a such that
$a^2 \equiv −1 \text{ (mod p) then }  p ≡ 1 \text{ (mod 4)}$

I am not sure how to solve this one. I know $p|a^2 + 1$, but I can't figure out how to relate this to p modulo 4.

Comment: Euler's criterion: $\left(\dfrac ap\right)\equiv a^{\dfrac{p-1}{2}}\pmod p$ . Apply to $a=-1$.

Comment: You mean relate this to $\color{red}p$ mod $4$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that $p \not\mid a$. Thus, by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem), you have

$$a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Suppose that $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$, so $p = 4k + 3$ for some integer $k \ge 0$. Since $a^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p$, then from \eqref{eq1A} you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a^{4k + 2} & \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
(a^{2})^{2k + 1} & \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
(-1)^{2k + 1} & \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
-1 & \equiv 1 \pmod p \\
0 & \equiv 2 \pmod p
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This is, of course, not possible for odd primes $p$. Thus, you must have that $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more dupe answers to dupe FAQs. Doing so greatly complicates  organizing the site.